# Sort stacked bar plot by cumulative value in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am pretty new to R and i'm trying to get a stacked bar plot. My data looks like this:

```
    name    value1  value2
1   A       1118    239
2   B       647     31
3   C       316     1275
4   D       2064    230
5   E       231     85
```

I need a horizontal bar graph with stacked values, this is as far as i can get with my limited R skills (and most of that is also copy-pasted):

```
melted <- melt(data, id.vars=c("name"))

melted$name <- factor(
  melted$name, 
  levels=rev(sort(unique(melted$name))), 
  ordered=TRUE
)

melted2 <- melted[order(melted$value),]

ggplot(melted2, aes(x= name, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()
```

It even took me several hours to get to this point, with witch I am pretty content as far as looks go, this is the produced output

[image]

What I now want to do is to get the bars ordered by summed up value (D is first, followed by C, A, B, E). I googled and tried some `reorder` and `order` stuff, but I simply can't get it to behave like I want it to. I'm sure the solution has to be pretty simple, so I hope you guys can help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph

Comment: I already saw that page, but can't seem to be able to work it into my own code... Can you give me a hint how to implement into my routine? Sorry that I'm such a noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am not down or keeping up with all the latest changes in ggplot, but here is one way you could remedy this

I used your idea to set up the factor levels of `name` but based on the grouped sums. You might also find `order = variable` useful at some point, which will order the bar colors based on the variable, but not needed here

```
data <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "name    value1  value2
1   A       1118    239
2   B       647     31
3   C       316     1275
4   D       2064    230
5   E       231     85")

library('reshape2')
library('ggplot2')

melted <- melt(data, id.vars=c("name"))

melted <- within(melted, {
  name <- factor(name, levels = names(sort(tapply(value, name, sum))))
})

levels(melted$name)
# [1] "E" "B" "A" "C" "D"

ggplot(melted, aes(x= name, y = value, fill = variable, order = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use the `dplyr` package to set up a total column in your data frame and use that to sort. 
The approach would look something like this.

```
m <- melted %>% group_by(name) %>% 
     mutate(total = sum(value) ) %>% 
     ungroup() %>%
     arrange(total) %>%
     mutate(name = factor(name, levels = unique(as.character(name))) )

ggplot(m, aes(x = name, y = value, fill = variable)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that trying below code.

- using `tidyr` package instead to `reshape2` package

  ```
  library(ggplot2)
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)

  data <- read.table(text = "
                     class value1 value2
                     A     1118   239
                     B     647    31
                     C     316    1275
                     D     2064   230
                     E     231    85", header = TRUE)

      pd <- gather(data, key, value, -class) %>% 
        mutate(class = factor(class, levels = tapply(value, class, sum) %>% sort %>% names))

      pd %>% ggplot(aes(x = class, y = value, fill = key, order = class)) + 
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    coord_flip()
  ```